# #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I am tyring to insert information into my table.. I did not start having problems with this until I added the column fname, once I added this I would get the error #1064 You have an error in your Sql syntax; could someone please help??  I also try switching the column name to first and it still did not work..

```
INSERT INTO `project`.`users` (`id`,'fname', `username`, `hash`,) VALUES(1,'name', 'caesar', '$1$50$GHABNWBNE/o4VL7QjmQ6x0');
```

Comment: remove the comma `hash`,) and replace ' by `

Comment: @GuilhemHoffmann Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong placed singlequotes (replace with  `) and a stray comma:

```
INSERT INTO `project`.`users` (`id`,'fname', `username`, `hash`,) 
                                    ^ here^                     ^ here
VALUES(1,'name', 'caesar', '$1$50$GHABNWBNE/o4VL7QjmQ6x0');
```

Removing that you end up with:

```
INSERT INTO `project`.`users` (`id`,`fname`, `username`, `hash`) 
    VALUES(1,'name', 'caesar', '$1$50$GHABNWBNE/o4VL7QjmQ6x0');
```

Comment: Thank you so much Felipe Silva.. I have literally been working on that for an hour or two now!!

Comment: @user3038531. If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Just correct your syntax by

- replacing ' by `
- Remove comma in hash,)

The following should work:

```
INSERT INTO `project`.`users` (`id`,`fname`, `username`, `hash`) 
VALUES(1,'name', 'caesar', '$1$50$GHABNWBNE/o4VL7QjmQ6x0');
```